# How to put sequential numbers only at end of the repeated lines

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file with some repeated lines. I want to put a sequential number only at the end of these repetitions.

Example.

**Input:**

```
Jose da Silva
Jose da Silva
Fulano de Tal
Jose da Silva
Sicrano Pereira
Ze Ruela
Sicrano Pereira
Jose da Silva
```

**Output:**

```
Jose da Silva #1
Jose da Silva #2
Fulano de Tal
Jose da Silva #3
Sicrano Pereira #1
Ze Ruela
Sicrano Pereira #2
Jose da Silva #4
```

I cannot sort these lines. They have to appear on the same order.

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop twice:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {count[$0]++; next} 
     count[$0]>1 {$0=$0 FS "#"++times[$0]}
     1' file file
```

That is: the first time, count how many times each line occurs. The second time, keep appending an incrementing number to those that appear more than once.

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {count[$0]++; next} count[$0]>1 {$0=$0 FS "#"++times[$0]}1' file file
Jose da Silva #1
Jose da Silva #2
Fulano de Tal
Jose da Silva #3
Sicrano Pereira #1
Ze Ruela
Sicrano Pereira #2
Jose da Silva #4
```

Comment: I was thinking in a sed solution cause awk is a little obscure for me. But thanks! It worked very well here!

Comment: @meleu for these cases, `sed` can be way more obscure than `awk` : ) Did you understand the reasoning of my answer? I hope it is clear.

Comment: Oh man! I've just realized that the original file is numbered followed by a colon, and then the names. I was cutting that numbers with `cut -d: -f2`
And later I will need these original line numbers... I'll do another question because I think this answer is perfect for my original question and can help another users...

Comment: I think this answer is perfect for my original question and can help another users... Maybe is more useful to do another question. What do you think?

Comment: @meleu yes, if you have a different problem, ask a different question.

Comment: I did it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317474/how-to-put-sequential-numbers-at-the-end-of-repeated-data-in-a-line